# How to get line height in percentage using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using this I get the full line-height value in px i want in percentage.

```
<div style="line-height:78%" id="example">This is HTML.</div>
<script>
    $('#example').css('line-height');
    /* Return 54px; but needed is 78% */
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#example')[0].style['line-height'];
```

You will get exact line-height that is set in inline style.